# I am trying to compare two strings in oracle pl sql but i got error like PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, string-comparison

i am trying to compare two strings with

```
IF  (   (NVL(TO_CHAR(LV_SUPP_SI_N), 'A') <> NVL(TO_CHAR(LV_SUPP_SI_O), 'A')) 
     OR (LV_SUPP_SI_N IS NULL  AND  LV_SUPP_SI_O IS NOT NULL)
     OR (LV_SUPP_SI_N IS NOT NULL  AND  LV_SUPP_SI_O IS NULL)
```

I want to know just how to compare `LV_SUPP_SI_N` to `LV_SUPP_SI_O` this value which is any data type

- here  `LV_SUPP_SI_N`  --new value means table values I don't know which data type it is either number, date or varchar
- `LV_SUPP_SI_O`  --same as above

both are not equal then I am trying to insert into one table, at that time i am getting error like

> Error occure while insertion due to: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Comment: "this value which is any data type" ... what do you mean, that it is "any data type"?

Answer (score 0):

```
if LV_SUPP_SI_N || 'A' <> LV_SUPP_SI_O || 'A' then ...
```